# assertj: compare fields between dto and entity classes

Tags: java, assertj

I need to compare a `DTO` class with its `Entity` class.

For example, an `AddressDTO` class would be:

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AddressDTO {

    private StringTypeDTO text;
    private List<StringTypeDTO> line;
    private StringTypeDTO city;
    private StringTypeDTO district;
    private StringTypeDTO state;
    private StringTypeDTO postalCode;
    private StringTypeDTO country;

}
```

and my `AddressEntity` class would be:

```java
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Address {

    private StringType text;
    private List<StringType> line;
    private StringType city;
    private StringType district;
    private StringType state;
    private StringType postalCode;
    private StringType country;

}
```

Is there any way to compare those two objects using `assertj`?

`StringType`:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StringTypeDTO {

    private String value;
    
}
```

And `StringType`:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StringType {

    private String value;
    
}
```

I want to avoid to make code like:

```
assertThat dto.field1 is equals to entity.field1 of object
assertThat dto.field2 is equals to entity.field2 of object
assertThat dto.field3 is equals to entity.field3 of object
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [field-by-field recursive comparison](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison) is what you are looking for:

```
AddressDTO addressDTO = new AddressDTO(...);
AddressEntity addressEntity = new AddressEntity(...);

assertThat(addressDTO).usingRecursiveComparison()
                      .isEqualTo(addressEntity);
```

Comment: What about if a field of dto differs from entity? I mean, `dto.citydto <-> entity.city`?

Comment: that does not work as AssertJ can't know that it needs to compare `dto.citydto <-> entity.city`