# AssertJ: How to build custom and nested assertions

Tags: assertj

I need to compare one `PatientDTO dto` object with other one `PatientModel model` object.

Both classes are quite similar:

```java
class PatientDTO {
    private String name;
    private List<AddressDTO> address;

    // Constructors, getters and setters
}

class PatientModel {
    private String id;
    private String nameElement;
    private List<AddressModel> addressElement;

    // Constructors, getters and setters
}

class AddressDTO {
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private List<String> linesElement;

    // Constructors, getters and setters
}

class AddressModel {
    private String city;
    private String countryElement;
    private List<String> linesElement;

    // Constructors, getters and setters
}
```

Main differences are:

- Some fields are not present on `DTO`s: `PatientDTO.id` doesn't exist.
- Some field names contains suffixes on `Model` classes: `PatientDTO.name <> PatientModel.nameElement`.

Other issue I like to solve, is that:

- `Address` related assertion should be shared. I mean, `Address`-like classes are present on other classes, for exemple, `Organization`, `Practitioner`...

I'd like to build an assertion like this:

```
PatientDTO patientDTO;
PatientModel patientModel;

assertThat(patientDTO).isEqual(patientModel);
```

Shortly:

1. Should I build a custom assertion?
2. Should I have an assertion for `Address` an other one for `Patient` containing previous `Address` assertion? How could I get this?
3. What aboud `Address` assertion for `Patient`, `Organization`

What I want to avoid is code like this:

```
assertThat(patientDTO).anySatisfy(p->{
    assertThat(p.getName()).withFailMessage("expected name: "+ p.getAddress().getCity()).isEqualTo(patientModel.getNameElement());
    assertThat(p.getAddress().getCity()).withFailMessage("expected city: "+ p.getAddress().getCity()).isEqualTo(patientModel.getCityElement());
    assertThat(p.getAddress().getCountry()).withFailMessage("expected country: "+ p.getAddress().getCountry()).isEqualTo(patientModel.getCountryElement());
    ...
    }
);
```

I want to avoid above code since `Patient` classes are really large. Here I've shorted them for clarity purpouses.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The [field-by-field recursive comparison](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-recursive-comparison) could help for this purpose:

```
PatientDTO patientDTO = new PatientDTO(...);
PatientModel patientModel = new PatientModel(...);

assertThat(patientDTO).usingRecursiveComparison()
                      .isEqualTo(patientModel);
```

> Some fields are not present on `DTO`s: `PatientDTO.id` doesn't exist.

There are a few methods that can be used to tune the comparison and ignore fields:

- Directly with [`ignoringFields(String…​ fieldsToIgnore)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/RecursiveComparisonAssert.html#ignoringFields(java.lang.String...))
- By regexes with [`ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes(String…​ regexes)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/RecursiveComparisonAssert.html#ignoringFieldsMatchingRegexes(java.lang.String...))
- By types with [`ignoringFieldsOfTypes(Class…​ typesToIgnore)`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/RecursiveComparisonAssert.html#ignoringFieldsOfTypes(java.lang.Class...))

> Some field names contains suffixes on `Model` classes: `PatientDTO.name <> PatientModel.nameElement`.

This is currently not supported and was also asked in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70381488/9714611. We plan to raise a feature request about it and I will update the answer once the issue link is ready.

> `Address` related assertion should be shared. I mean, `Address`-like classes are present on other classes, for exemple, `Organization`, `Practitioner`...

If the target is always `isEqualTo`, probably a custom assertion implementation is not needed as long as the limitation of the recursive comparison about not being able to compare fields with different names is not a show-stopper. These fields would require ad-hoc comparison until a better solution is available.

If the target is to provide assertions in a domain-specific language, like:

```
assertThat(patientDTO).hasAddress(addressDTO);
```

then a [custom assertion](https://assertj.github.io/doc/#assertj-core-custom-assertions) implementation can be added.

Also, there is an [assertions generator](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-assertions-generator) with plugins for [Maven](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-assertions-generator-maven-plugin) and [Gradle](https://github.com/assertj/assertj-generator-gradle-plugin) that can be used to generate assertions based on the class attributes.